# ant zip: how to add prefix to all all files/dirs

Tags: ant, zip, prefix

```
<zip destfile="/tmp/abc.zip" >
  <fileset ...>
     ....
  </fileset>

  <zipfileset prefix="hello" >
  </zipfilest>

</zip>
```

I would like to add prefix foo_bar_3.0 to all the files when creating the zip. Is there a way? Thanks.

Comment: Is that a directory prefix, a filename prefix, or ... something else?

Comment: directory prefix to all entries, like <zip prefix=foo_bar_3.0> ...</zip>

Answer (score 1):

Your question is a bit confusing. for the zipfileset part you already append the prefix "hello" to all files in that set.

If you are asking for the fileset part the ant documentation has the right example for you, at the bottom of the page https://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/zip.html you'll find this example:

```
<zip destfile="${dist}/manual.zip">
    <mappedresources>
        <fileset dir="htdocs/manual"/>
        <globmapper from="*" to="docs/user-guide/*"/>
    </mappedresources>
</zip>
```

and here's the documentation for mappers https://ant.apache.org/manual/Types/mapper.html, a simple globmapper will do for you.

Answer (score 0):

You can accomplish your goal by staging all the files in a temporary directory with the structure of your choosing.  Once the files are staged, simply zip up the directory and clean out the staging area.

```
<target name="zip.with.prefix">
    <copy todir="tmp/dir1">
        <fileset dir="dir1"/>
    </copy>
    <copy todir="tmp/dir2">
        <fileset dir="dir2"/>
    </copy>
    <zip destfile="abc.zip" basedir="tmp"/>
    <delete dir="tmp"/>
</target>
```